# setMapType for google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, preferenceactivity

I want to make a PreferenceActivity and set map type of google map.
I see that it can be with command mGoogleMap.setMapType(Googlemap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

How i can do it with SharedPreferences?

I use a ListPreference at preferences.xml with an array for values

```
 <string-array name="listValues">
 <item>"MAP_TYPE_NORMAL"</item>
 <item>"MAP_TYPE_HYBRID"</item>
 <item>"MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN"</item>
</string-array>
```

so in main activity i made a function to get these values.

```
private void getPrefs() {
        // Get the xml/preferences.xml preferences  
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

How now i can set the type as argument like

```
mGoogleMap.setMapType(Googlemap.arg);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the preference, map to `GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_XXX` and send to `GoogleMap.setMapType`

```
String prefValue = prefs.getString(...);
int mapType;
if ("MAP_TYPE_NORMAL".equals(prefValue)) {
    mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
} else if (...) {
    ...
}
googleMap.setMapType(mapType);
```

Comment: Thanks that is ok. The solution was not so complicate. I have now an other question. Where i must call getPrefs(); I call the function when click the settings button, but the settings dont confirmed when go back from preferences window.

Comment: @user1856182 `onResume` should be fine.